# How to show the 'preview' screen after picking a photo using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios

In my project, i am using UIImagePickerController to allow the user to pick a photo from the iDevice gallery (that is from the saved images, NOT camera)

I would like to present the preview screen as done when picking an image in the native messages app (it has 'cancel/choose button at the bottom)

I tried setting the allowEditing to YES, but the result is 'Move and Scale' which i dont want.

Is there a way to do it, or do i need to create this 'preview' view in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad news, but the Move and Scale is a view you'll have when setting allowEditing to YES. If you want something else, you'll have to built it by yourself (or to find some open source for it)...